# Why Repository could not be reached in Dataform, with connection to Gitlab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, dataform

I have implement data transformation pipeline on Google Cloud Composer, by using

1. "DataformCreateCompilationResultOperator" to create comilation on Dataform
2. "DataformCreateWorkFlowInvocationOperator" to create invocation to run models on Dataform

which process by order 1 >> 2

The error happen when "DataformCreateCompilationResultOperator" try to create compilation on Dataform which connected to Gitlab repository. It raised this error

**google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Remote repository 'xxx.git' could not be reached.**

[Google's same case suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdbMh.png)

ref : [Google's troubleshooting link](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/troubleshooting#remote_repository_cannot_be_reached_genericinvalid_argument)

After that I try to find solution on Google's troubleshooting, the google inform that "There is no need to take any action. Unless GitHub or GitLab issues persist, the subsequent scheduled releases can be successful"

[DagRun after i set retries=2 to Airflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey94n.png)

After that I add number of retries to 2 (1 min interval) to DAG config, it was  retried and it can be proceed but it not stable, sometimes they need 5 retries.

The question is, what is the cause of this error and how to solved it, with appropriate action,  the "retry" method is not stable, maybe the error will happen more often in the future.

Anythought?, Thank you very much